# ¿Qué se entiende por "viejoven" y "joviejo"?

Tags: españa, sustantivos, neologismos

Las voces *viejoven* y *joviejo* se usan, al menos en España, para designar a los viejos con alma de joven, y a los jóvenes con alma de viejo... o eso creía yo (y la gente de mi trabajo, que opina como yo). Acabo de leer un artículo en el que me da la sensación de que los términos se usan [al revés](http://www.bfacemag.es/lifestyle/viejoven/):

> [Sobre "viejoven":] Tienes menos de 30 años, sí, pero el poleo menta entra mejor que una cerveza y a ti el thai que habéis comido no te ha dejado muy fino.
>
> [Sobre "joviejo":] Intenta tener por lo menos 40 durante unas horas al día. Porque después, puede que quieras tener 20. Y será demasiado tarde. Serás un joviejo.

No sé si estos neologismos se usan también en Hispanoamérica, así que centro la pregunta en España. ¿Qué se entiende pues generalmente cuando se usan las voces *viejoven* y *joviejo*?

Comment: Nunca había oído *joviejo* -que mal suena por cierto- y *viejoven* también pensaba que era alguien mayor que se siente más joven.

Comment: @blonfu pues tú espera que igual lo estaba yo entendiendo [al revés](https://www.larazon.es/es-usted-joviejo-o-viejoven-MO19604392), y se ve que no soy el único, así que quien sepa responder que nos lo aclare... :-D

Comment: Me recuerda a aquello de _veintegenarios_ que cantaban Albert Pla y Extremoduro.

Comment: no parece que está muy claro: https://www.fundeu.es/blog/eres-un-viejoven-y-lo-sabes/

Comment: @blonfu gran enlace, eso da para respuesta...

Answer (score 2):

Resumen: el significado original era "viejo con aires de joven" y ese parece su uso mayoritario en Sudamérica. En España los usos están más mezclados, habiendo tanto en un sentido como en el contrario.

---

[Esta página](https://www.trambolico.com/viejoven.html) atribuye la creación del término a los cómicos de La Hora Chanante en 2014.
Sin embargo, una búsqueda del término en Google en páginas anteriores a 2014 arroja bastantes resultados... De los más antiguos que veo inicialmente, uno sería el blog [Mundo Viejoven](http://mundoviejoven.blogspot.com/), de 2009. Pero es que si restringimos a anteriores a 2009 nos encontramos [este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BzRAU-Ovfg&t=50) de 2008 de... Muchachada Nui, es decir, de los cómicos de La Hora Chanante :D en donde ya medio se define el término:

> —¿Eres joven o vieja? [...]
>   —Joven... Soy joven; pero vieja a la vez. Soy viejoven.
>   —Viejoven...
>   —Claro, como el cantante de La Unión.
>   —Hombre, el cantante de La Unión es viejo sin más...

Lo interpreto como "viejo con aires de joven" por el símil con el cantante.

Pero podemos seguir tirando del hilo y encontrarnos [este blog de 2006](http://www.juankiblog.com/2006/11/sobre-mi.html) donde alguien se define a sí mismo como *viejoven* con 24 años:

> Tengo 24 años y soy un *viejoven* con un insano exceso de tiempo libre entre mis manos. [...] No me gusta el fútbol, no disfruto al salir de fiesta y prefiero quedarme en casa [...]

Lo que sería "joven con aires de viejo". De momento vamos 1-1.

Seguimos remontándonos en el tiempo y vemos [este artículo de 2003](http://www.letras.mysite.com/rojas251203.htm) de un portal chileno donde se describe al poeta Gonzalo Rojas como *viejoven* de 80 años:

> Un poeta que traspasados los ochenta es un "viejoven" que escribe cada día al amanecer cuando el duchazo frío le enciende las arteriolas del seso.

Curiosamente el mismo término que se usa en [esta otra entrada del 2002](http://sobrelibros.cl/al-silencio-de-gonzalo-rojas/), chilena también:

> Al fin y al cabo sentía la necesidad de aproximarme a una crítica literaria de Rojas, entre tanta alabanza a la exquisita *ars amandi* del Viejoven están sus poemas, los que debían suspender mi incredulidad ante homenajes prepóstumos y ediciones definitivas.

En ambas se usa con el sentido de "viejo con espíritu joven".

Hasta llegar a lo que parece la coincidencia más antigua, en este [relato inserto en una revisa mexicana de octubre de 2002](http://www.revistadelauniversidad.unam.mx/historico/10653.pdf) [PDF], que además es de las pocas ocasiones en que casi define el término:

> Apunto de empezar el segundo Tic-Tac se acerca **un joven avejentado y chaparrón**. Sin protocolo ni miramientos se sienta en el banco que está libre y empieza a hablar casi sin mirarnos. [...] Mientras el **viejoven** chaparrón se aleja nuevamente sin mirarnos, Albarrán baja la voz.

Y de nuevo cambiamos el sentido, "joven avejentado".

Tenemos entonces que, según dónde mires, encontrarás un significado u otro:

- Para los de Muchachada Nui y los blogs chilenos, parece que sería "viejo con aires de joven".
- Para el del blog de 2006 y el del relato mexicano, sería "joven con aires de viejo".

Pero esto es solo mirando resultados web. ¿Y si miramos libros físicos?
Lamentablemente, no aparecen resultados en CORDE, CREA ni CORPES XXI (que yo haya visto)... pero por suerte, podemos [buscar en Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=viejoven&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999):

> Tenemos [Nicanor] Parra para rato si ponemos atención a la vitalidad de este "viejoven" a quien el Nobel no lo deshonraría...
>   <sub>Faride Zerán, *Al pie de la letra*, 1995.</sub>
>
> Claro, con tantos años como ya tenemos nosotros cuatro, algo has envejecido, aunque no tanto: eres una persona viejoven, bastante viejoven...
>   <sub>M. Lerner, *Mundi*, 1986.</sub>

En ambos casos se interpreta como "viejo con aires de joven", deshaciendo el cuasi-empate que teníamos.

Parece claro entonces que **el significado original era el de "viejo con aires de joven"**, o al menos es el más habitual en los textos encontrados.
Otra cosa es que al extenderse su uso, especialmente a España, haya podido tomar la interpretación opuesta, que al final se dará por igualmente válida lo queramos o no. No sería el primer caso de una palabra que quiere decir al mismo tiempo una cosa y su contraria ;)

Lo que sí que está claro es que la palabra es de origen sudamericano (los resultados más antiguos son de autores chilenos, argentinos y mexicanos) y sorprende su "edad": ¡casi 40 años!
Viendo cómo la tratamos de novedosa, diríase que la palabra en sí también es viejoven, a su manera :)

---

Nota: el escaso número de usos que aparecen para España anteriores al vídeo de Muchachada Nui, me hace preguntarme si Joaquín Reyes será aficionado a la literatura chilena...